# Perplexing if condition in jQuery merge function

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I was just going through the code of jQuery and came across the function merge. I checked out the code of this function:

```
merge: function( first, second ) {
    var len = +second.length,
        j = 0,
        i = first.length;

    while ( j < len ) {
        first[ i++ ] = second[ j++ ];
    }

    // Support: IE<9
    // Workaround casting of .length to NaN on otherwise arraylike objects (e.g., NodeLists)

    if ( len !== len ) {
        while ( second[j] !== undefined ) {
            first[ i++ ] = second[ j++ ];
        }
    }

    first.length = i;

    return first;
},
```

Now if you go through the code, you will come across the following `if` check:

```
if ( len !== len )
```

This somehow doesn't make sense to me, what exactly is this check for, and what is it doing ?

`len` is clearly defined a few lines above, like so:

```
var len = +second.length;
```

So why would someone check if `len !== len`? This somehow doesn't make sense to me. Can somebody explain?

Comment: It doesn't look sensible but appearantly `NaN !== NaN // true`. Don't ask me why... `isNaN(len)` looks more logical to me.

Comment: @Jonathan isNaN check for `not a Number` (string, boolean ...) , `len !== len` check for `NaN` value

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference. I'm coming to think `NaN !== NaN` is the most wtf in JS I've ever seen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a check for `NaN` (as correctly pointed out in @Jonathan's comment). From the excellent [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN):

> `NaN` compares unequal (via ==, !=, ===, and !==) to any other value -- including to another `NaN` value.  Use `Number.isNaN()` or `isNaN()` to most clearly determine whether a value is `NaN`.  Or perform a self-comparison: `NaN`, and only `NaN`, will compare unequal to itself.

Comment: Regardless, it is a horrible way of writing more readable code.

Comment: It's a fairly common js idiom, but you're right - it is funny looking for non-js devs. I think the comment preceding the line in the jQuery snippet mitigates some of the readability concern as well.

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator ([unary plus](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/)) in the assignment `var len = +second.length;` tries to convert the value `second.length` into a number by internally calling `valueOf()` and `toString()`. If the conversion to a number fails, it will assign `NaN` to the variable `len`. As previously stated, `len !== len` is a way to check for `NaN`.

Comment: `by internally calling valueOf() and toString()` Do you mean the [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)?

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer with a link to documentation of the unary plus operator.

Comment: But how do you reckon it is "calling valueOf() and toString()"?

Comment: @NathanWilson , so your basically checking if `NaN !== NaN` , when u say `len !== len` ?

Comment: also by internally ... what do u mean ? internally where ?

Comment: It is checking whether `len` is a number. `len !== len` will evaluate to either `false` if `len` is a number or `true` if `len` is `NaN`. The unary plus operator in `+second.length` calls `valueOf()` internally in the code of the unary `+` operator. The unary `+` operator will ensure that `len` gets set to either a number or `NaN`.